# Facebook App permission settings

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post on my Facebook page with PHP.

I have set up the Facebook API (version 4) and collected all the data I need, like `AppId`, `Secret Key`, `Access Token` and now when I try to post on my page like this:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');

define("FACEBOOK_CONSUMER_KEY", "{myKey}");
define("FACEBOOK_CONSUMER_SECRET", "{mySecret}");
define("FACEBOOK_ACCESS_KEY", "{myToken}");

Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(FACEBOOK_CONSUMER_KEY, FACEBOOK_CONSUMER_SECRET);
$session = new Facebook\FacebookSession(FACEBOOK_ACCESS_KEY);

$message = array(
    "message" => "It works!",
    "link" => "http://www.google.de",
    //"picture" => "url to picture",
    //"name" => "Picture title",
    //"description" => "Description",
);

$response = ( new Facebook\FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/{myPageId}/feed', $message ) )->execute()->getGraphObject();

echo $response->getProperty('id');
```

Unfortunately I get the following error evertime I execute it:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookPermissionException' with message '(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action' in {myPath}/FacebookRequestException.php:128
Stack trace:
#0 {myPath}/FacebookRequest.php(280): Facebook\FacebookRequestException::create('{"error":{"mess...', Object(stdClass), 403)
#1 {myPath}/test.php(21): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute()
#2 {main}
  thrown in {myPath}/FacebookRequestException.php on line 128
```

How can I setup the Facebook App that it work correctly?

Comment: `try/catch` that attempt to post, you'll find the error there.

Comment: i get the same error as before. I think I have to setup my Facebook App in an other way...am I wrong?

Comment: you need to have the `publish_actions` permission enabled to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the login flow to authorize your app first. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/4.0.0